# Pie chartjs con foreach

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, foreach

quiero hacer un pie chart con angularjs, si meto los datos a mano me sale perfecto. El problema llega cuando intento mostrar los datos sacados de una base de datos.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

El var data tendría que tener algo como

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['FECHA', 'HORAS'],
     foreach(d in datosHoras){
      ['d.day', d.seconds]
}
])
```

Pero no me dibuja nada.
Gracias.

Comment: El último trozo de código no es javascript válido, ¿qué quieres hacer?

Comment: Algo asi, que pueda recorrer un array y mostrarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo único que te falta es solo saber como unir esos array seria de esta forma, para corregir el error de sintaxis

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    [
        ['FECHA', 'HORAS']
    ].concat(
        datosHoras.map(d => ['d.day', d.seconds])
    )
)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó a la perfección.